# `ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref` while importing from scikit learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

**PROBLEM DESCRIPTION**

I'm getting this error while calling a python script :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/t/file/file.py", line 61, in <module>
    from sklearn.externals import joblib
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import sys, os, time, cStringIO, traceback, warnings, weakref, collections
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/weakref.py", line 14, in <module>
    from _weakref import (
ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref
Failed to load file
```

As stated in the error log, this happens when I import :

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
```

**NOTES**

NOTE 1: 
calling `import sklearn` **alone** also produces this error.

NOTE 2: 
Running without any other import statements and the rest of the code in the file commented out also produces the error

NOTE 3: 
Objective-C code is calling this python file via the Python C API (https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/index.html).
**This works perfectly on another machine with the exact same specs and OS** (see details below).

NOTE 4: 
There is **no error** if I call Python from the terminal then `import sklearn` OR `from sklearn.externals import joblib` (Without calling from objective-C)

NOTE 5: 
I don't think I have any virtual environments installed. I've tried calling `pyenv`, `pyvenv` and `virtualenv` on the terminal. Always getting `-bash: pyvenv: command not found`

**DETAILS**

Both machines I've tried this on are MacBook Pros with identical specs running Mac OS 10.13. (The code works on one of them and fails on the other)

I've tried this on the machine the code fails on :

I've added the following lines to both (a) the script called by the executable AND (b) on the python CLI on the terminal :

```
print ">>>>>>>>>"+str(sys.executable)
print ">>>>>>>>>"+str(sys.version)
print "++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"
for p in sys.path: 
    print p
```

Output from the script that's failing :

```
>>>>>>>>>/anaconda2/bin/python
>>>>>>>>>2.7.10 (default, Feb  6 2017, 23:53:20) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)]
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
/anaconda2/lib/python27.zip
/anaconda2/lib/python2.7
/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/aeosa
~/Desktop/Test Software/Sources/*****/path/to/.py/file/*****/Classification
```

Output on the terminal :

```
>>> sys.executable
'/anaconda2/bin/python'

>>> sys.version
'2.7.14 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Dec  7 2017, 11:07:58) \n[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)]'

>>> for p in sys.path:
...     print p
... 

/anaconda2/lib/python27.zip
/anaconda2/lib/python2.7
/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/aeosa
```

Basically, getting the same thing, except for the version, and that I'm (obviously) also seeing the path to the .py file in the search path.

Comment: can you post the output of `which python python3`

Answer (score 1):

Try to uninstall, then install again your package:

`conda uninstall scikit-learn`

Answer (score 0):

Try following the below commands. I faced a similar issue I was able to resolve it using:

1. `sudo pip uninstall scikit-learn`
2. `sudo pip install -U scikit-learn`

Make sure following dependencies are met:
Scikit-learn requires:

`Python (>= 2.7 or >= 3.3)
 NumPy (>= 1.8.2),
 SciPy (>= 0.13.3)`

Also checkout this [Link](https://shanshanchen.com/2013/05/29/install-numpy-scipy-scikit-learn-on-mac-os-x-for-data-miners/).

For Note5:
`pyenv` command does not exist in `Python 2`.
You can use `virtualenv` instead.